# C++17 class template deduction

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to under the class template deduction in C++17.
I wrote a sample class template that can be constructed without specifying the template types. `std::unique_ptr` can't be constructed without specifying the types.
I need help in understanding why that is the case.

Code compiled using clang 5.0

```
// Please don't worry about memory leaks, etc. This is sample code anyways.
template<typename T, typename deleter = std::default_delete<T>>
struct Sample
{
T* x_;
deleter func_;

Sample(T* x = nullptr, deleter func = deleter{})
: x_(x)
, func_(func)
{
}
};

auto sample = Sample(new int(10));
std::cout << *(sample.x_) << '\n';
```

The below code fails to compile.

```
auto ptr = std::unique_ptr(new int(10));
```

Comment: Would you perhaps care to tell us what the error message is?

Comment: Meta tip: When you're tempted to say "please ignore all the details", try working *with* all the details in place and see if the problem is still unclear. A lot of things are all about the details.

Comment: @KerrekSB if it did not compile meaning then isn't that obvious that the compiler complained to provide the template type ? what is there to care or not care ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't unique\_ptr's template arguments be deduced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109767/why-cant-unique-ptrs-template-arguments-be-deduced)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class template `std::unique_ptr` is more complicated than your toy example. Its primary ownership-taking constructor takes the form

```
unique_ptr<T, D>::unique_ptr(pointer p)
```

where `pointer` is either `D::pointer` or `remove_reference_t<D>::pointer` or `T*`. So if you wanted to deduce the class template arguments from the constructor, you would first need to know which deleter provides the pointer type, which leads to a circular dependency, and thus you cannot know what `T` and `D` should be from the constructor argument. To avoid any accidental misinterpretation, the Standard explicitly requires this constructor not to be usable in template argument deduction (thanks to @T.C. for pointing out the precise wording!).

A simple example is that for an argument of type `U*` you could deduce either `unique_ptr<U>` or `unique_ptr<U[]>`; neither is obviously better, and the wrong choice would be a disaster.

To cut a long story short, the class template arguments of `std::unique_ptr` are not deducible from constructor arguments, unlike in the case of `Sample`.

Comment: LWG added specific wording to say that deducing from the `pointer`-taking ctors is ill-formed, precisely due to the `T` vs `T[]` problem.

Comment: ok so try compiling without providing template type , if it fails to compile,then provide the types. This is what the feature is all about as far as i understand

Comment: @T.C.: But is there specific wording to effect that, or does it just follow naturally from the existing class definition? I didn't see any explicit guides.

Comment: They put it in the constructor's spec, [like this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/unique.ptr.single.ctor#8).

Comment: @T.C.: Ah yes, thanks. I'd say that could still be considered part of "this class template is more complicated", but I'll update the post to call out this explicit provision.