# Why can't unique_ptr's template arguments be deduced?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

When you have class template argument deduction available from C++17, why can't you deduce the template arguments of std::unique_ptr? For example, this gives me an error:

```
std::unique_ptr smp(new D);
```

That says "Argument list of class template is missing".

Shouldn't the template arguments (at least the pointer type) be deducable?

[See this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction):

> any declaration that specifies initialization of a variable and
>   variable template

Comment: Not an answer, but just wondering why you are not using `make_unique` in the first place..?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude C++17 adds class template deduction guides that use the constructor call to deduce the template types of the class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Then isn't the cited phrasing a little misleading from cppreference? (about to update question with the citation :) )

Comment: @JesperJuhl For me, I want to use the struct aggregate initializer. `make_unique` does not seem to support it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not going to repeat the rationale in [@NathanOliver's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51109812/817643), I'm just going to mention the *how* of it, the mechanics, which is what I think you are also after. You are right that if the constructor of `unique_ptr` looked merely like...

```
explicit unique_ptr( T* ) noexcept;
```

... it'd be possible to deduce `T`. The compiler generated deduction guide would work just fine. And that would be a problem, like Nathan illustrates. But the constructor is specified like this...

```
explicit unique_ptr( pointer p ) noexcept;
```

... where the alias `pointer` is specified as follows:

> `pointer` : `std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer` if that
>   type exists, otherwise `T*`. Must satisfy *NullablePointer*.

That specification essentially means that `pointer` must be an alias to `__some_meta_function<T>::type`. Everything on the left of `::type` is a non-deduced context, which is what prevents the deduction of `T` from `pointer`. That's how these sort of deduction guides could be made to fail even if `pointer` needed to be `T*` always. Just by making it a non-deduced context will prevent the viability of any deduction guide produced from that constructor.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 27):

Lets look at `new int` and `new int[10]`.  Both of those return an `int*`.  There is no way to tell if you should have `unique_ptr<int>` or `unique_ptr<int[]>`.  That right there is enough not to provide any sort of deduction guide.

Comment: I see the rationale, but isn't there some rule for this? Like, you have to explicitly define the template arguments if....

Comment: Oh, so make it default to use `unique_ptr<int>` and if you want the array for then you have to explicitly do so?  I would think that would be more bothersome to remember then to just always tell it what you want.

Comment: If that is the only intent, then better to have one more class like `std::unique_array_ptr` and have more convenient `std::unique_ptr`, rather than have something that is not convenient to use

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko what's inconvenient about `auto foo = make_unique<some_type>(some_initializer)`?

Comment: I need `std::unique_ptr` to track my pointer to array. `std::make_unique` initializes array with zeros. `std::make_unique_for_overwrite` will be available in C++20. Thus, if I want to create `unique_ptr`, I have to write type two times `std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[128])` instead of `std::unique_ptr(new char[128])`

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko Are you trying to make some sort of buffer that you are filling with data?  Any reason to not use a `std::vector` if that is the case?

Comment: @NathanOliver, correct. I do not use `std::vector` because like a `std::make_unique` it also fills memory with zeros. Also `std::vector` consists of Pointer + Size + Capacity. I do not need Size and Capacity after memory is allocated and initialized. Thus, I can save 16 bytes in a CPU Cache Line.

Comment: Surely the type of the deleter could at least be deduced when using `std::unique_ptr`'s binary constructors?

Answer (score 0):

So this is a side effect from those olden times at the beginning of C++, when the standard makers decided to have two different `delete` and `delete[]` operators for pointers to objects and pointers to arrays of objects.

In these modern times of C++, where we have templates (they weren't there from the beginning), `std::array` (for fixed sized arrays), inititalizer lists (for static fixed sized arrays) and `std::vector` (for dynamically sized arrays), almost nobody will need the `delete[]` operator anymore. I have never used it, and I wouldn't be surprised, if the vast majority of the readers of this question have not used it, either.

Removing `int* array = new int[5];` in favour of `auto* array = new std::array<int, 5>;` would simplify things and would enable safe conversion of pointers to `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`. But it would break old code, and so far, the C++ standard maintainers have been very keen on backwards compatibility.

Nobody stops you, though, from writing a small inlined templated wrapper function:

```
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> unique_obj_ptr(T* object) {
    static_assert(!std::is_pointer<T>::value, "Cannot use pointers to pointers here");
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(object);
}
```

Of course, you can also create a similiar function `shared_obj_ptr()` to create `std::shared_ptr`s, and if you really need them, you can also add `unique_arr_ptr()` and `shared_arr_ptr()`.

Comment: `new std::array<...>` does not work for dynamically sized arrays and `new std::vector<...>` wastes an allocation.

Comment: The replacement for `auto var = new TYPE[N]` (with non-constant `N`) is `auto var = std::vector<TYPE>(N)`. So no allocations are wasted, only the space for the currently used and allocated size of the vector inside the vector data structure is required extra. For non-trivial destructors, one of these two values, the array size, is also kept around in a hidden field for proper destruction by operator `delete []`. If wasting the other eight bytes for the current size worries you, then please add non-resizeable vectors to the standard library.

Comment: `auto var = std::vector<TYPE>(N)` is essentially a unique array. There is no shared or non-owning counterpart.