# Automatic template parameter deduction in unique_ptr and make_unique

Tags: c++, templates, unique-ptr, template-argument-deduction, class-template

Why do I get automatic template parameter deduction if I call class constructor directly but I do not get it in `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique`? Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <memory>
template <class T>
class C
{
public:
 C(const T * const t_) : t(t_) {}
 ~C(void) { delete t; }
private:
 const T * const t;
};
```

Example 1 (works):

```cpp
int main(void)
{
 const int * const t = new int;
 auto * const c = new C(t);
 return 0;
}
```

Example 2 (does not compile):

```cpp
int main(void)
{
 const int * const t = new int;
 auto * const c = new C(t);
 std::unique_ptr p(c); // class template argument deduction failed
 return 0;
}
```

Example 3 (works):

```cpp
int main(void)
{
 const int * const t = new int;
 const auto c = std::make_unique<C<int>>(t);
 return 0;
}
```

Example 4 (does not compile):

```cpp
int main(void)
{
 const int * const t = new int;

 // no matching function for call to ‘make_unique<template<class T> class C>(const int* const&)
 const auto c = std::make_unique<C>(t);
 return 0;
}
```

The code was compiled with `g++ -std=c++17` (gcc-11.2.0).

What is the problem in examples 2 and 4? How can one fix them?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The problem is that you are passing a `const int*`  to `unique_ptr`. How is it supposed to know that you want it to convert that argument to a `C<int>`?

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't use `new` and pointers everywhere in your code. Allocating on the stack and passing by reference should be your default options.

Comment: @super Actually, I pass `c` to `unique_ptr`.

Comment: `explicit unique_ptr(pointer p) noexcept;`. `pointer` here is `std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer`. So, to deduce argument, you need to know deleter type beforehand.

Comment: @S.V Ah, right. My bad.

Comment: @Genjutsu Adding an explicit destructor (`~C(void) { delete t; }`) to `C` does not solve the problem.

Comment: @S.V deleter is no the same as destructor. Please, refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109767/why-cant-unique-ptrs-template-arguments-be-deduced

Comment: @Genjutsu So, the conclusion is that automatic template parameter deduction does not work with `unique_ptr`? Or there is a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to solve it:

```cpp
template <class T>
auto MakeUnique(T t) 
{ return std::unique_ptr<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*t)>>(t); }

int main(void)
{
 const int * const t = new int;
 auto * const c = new C(t);
 auto p = MakeUnique(c);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In #2, CTAD is deliberately **disabled** for `std::unique_ptr` to avoid the issues with `std::unique_ptr(new T[10])`, which looks just like `std::unique_ptr(new T)` but needs `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

In #4, the **language** simply doesn’t support this: there’s no way to pass *any* class template as a template argument so as to do CTAD based on the function arguments inside `std::make_unique`.  (One could pass a class template with a specific (meta)signature, but that wouldn’t be appropriate for a general facility.)

Comment: In #2: Is there any way to tell `std::unique_ptr` to use `delete` (and not `delete []`)? It sounds like it would solve the problem. In #4: the intent is to call `C` constructor on `t` (here automatic template parameter has to work) and then create a `std::unique_ptr` out of the result. So, it seems, the problem is identical here to problem in #2, and so if #2 is resolved, then #4 should be resolved as well.

Comment: @S.V: The way to say to use `delete` is your answer.  `C`, not being a class, doesn’t have constructors; CTAD is *really* weird in that it examines the constructors declared for a class **template**.  #4 already knows it’s a single object since it’s not “`C[]`” (which can’t ever be used); you can, as I said, write a wrapper which accepts a certain kind of class template as a template template argument and uses CTAD to select a specialization of it.