# Can't constuct a std::unique_ptr with a lambda as a custom deleter

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, custom-deleter

I am trying to declare `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter:

```
using FILE = int;

FILE *f = nullptr;

std::unique_ptr pf(f, [](FILE *f) {});
```

but without a success. What is wrong?

How to use a lambda as a deleter? Do I really need `decltype`?

MSVC compiler error (std==C++17):

```
error C2641: cannot deduce template arguments for 'std::unique_ptr'
```

Comment: Quote from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr): "These two constructors are not selected by class template argument deduction." You can't use CTAD if you pass deleter, you have to provide template arguments.

Comment: Did you include ```memory``` header in your code? You also have to explicit declare the pointee type

Comment: @0xNIC yes I did

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70354413/automatic-template-parameter-deduction-in-unique-ptr-and-make-unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot use [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) for constructing a [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) if you pass a deleter.

If you need to use a lambda you can store it in a variable and use `decltype` to infer its type:

```
#include <memory>

//...

using FILE = int;
FILE* f = nullptr;
auto my_lambda = [](FILE* f) {};
std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(my_lambda)> pf(f, my_lambda);
```

[Live demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bz1EsGfTM)

---

As @NebularNoise commented, c++20 supports lambdas in unevaluated contexts. If you can use c++20 (you mentioned you currently use c++17) you can make it a bit shorter:

```
using FILE = int;
FILE* f = nullptr;
std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype([](FILE* f) {})> pf(f);
```

[Live demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3Mb9seWzW)

Comment: C++20 makes lambdas available in unevaluated contexts, so if C++20 is an option, it could be shortened to the following:
```std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype([](FILE* f) {})> pf(f);```